# Copy a word doc and fill the copy with output text

Tags: c#, ms-word, output, interop, savefiledialog

I'm searching for how to fill word .doc file with data from my c# app that have stored data into SQL CE db.

All approuches I found out 'till now, are to use the source .doc file to search and replace variables with the values and save it in the original, that seems great, but I need to:

1° Copy the source .doc file to a place where the user wants, using savefiledialog.

2° Then the copy is fulfilled with the data I want and then saved.

Because the .doc file will be the model for a lot of profiles later, so I can't edit the original, and the user must select where he wants to save it.

Or Maybe:

1° Edit the .doc model, then savefiledialog (without altering the model .doc)

EDIT: Could solve it, to anyone interested in future:

```
private void CreateWordDocument(object fileName,
            object saveAs)
        {
            //Set Missing Value parameter - used to represent
            // a missing value when calling methods through
            // interop.
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            //Setup the Word.Application class.
            Word.Application wordApp =
                new Word.Application();

            //Setup our Word.Document class we'll use.
            Word.Document aDoc = null;

            // Check to see that file exists
            if (File.Exists((string)fileName))
            {
                DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

                object readOnly = false;
                object isVisible = false;

                //Set Word to be not visible.
                wordApp.Visible = false;

                //Open the word document
                aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing,
                    ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing);

                // Activate the document
                aDoc.Activate();

                // Find Place Holders and Replace them with Values.
                this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "$$name$$", "Zach Smith");


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Arquivo faltando.");
                return;
            }


            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Documento do Word|*.doc";
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Salvar";
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Ficha Reg";
            if (DialogResult.OK == saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog())
            {
                string docName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                if (docName.Length > 0)
                {


                    saveAs = (object)docName;
                    //Save the document as the correct file name.
                    aDoc.SaveAs(ref saveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);





                }
            }


            //Close the document - you have to do this.
            aDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            MessageBox.Show("File created.");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is simply a helper method to find/replace 
        /// text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="WordApp">Word Application to use</param>
        /// <param name="findText">Text to find</param>
        /// <param name="replaceWithText">Replacement text</param>
        private void FindAndReplace(Word.Application WordApp,
                                    object findText,
                                    object replaceWithText)
        {
            object matchCase = true;
            object matchWholeWord = true;
            object matchWildCards = false;
            object matchSoundsLike = false;
            object nmatchAllWordForms = false;
            object forward = true;
            object format = false;
            object matchKashida = false;
            object matchDiacritics = false;
            object matchAlefHamza = false;
            object matchControl = false;
            object read_only = false;
            object visible = true;
            object replace = 2;
            object wrap = 1;

            WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText,
                ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike,
                ref nmatchAllWordForms, ref forward,
                ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
                ref replace, ref matchKashida,
                ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza,
                ref matchControl);
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            CreateWordDocument(@"C:\Users\Blind\Desktop\FICHA.doc", "");
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to approach this is to save the *.doc file as a *template* (*.dot) then usae the `Documents.Add` method to create a copy from the template.